# strangeproblem with http request URL Parameter in web service php

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, stored-procedures, httprequest

Guys I'm working on the developing an app and I have a very strange problem. I have a database and a web service, I wrote a number of procedures and functions in the database and all well work within the environment MySql, but when I use from URL Request, not show true query (Always run else condition and show me record 'xxxx' that record for response when I understand send data from isn't true and invalid and not show me blank json like '[ ]'), almost all things test, like character set,... (all things that been comments) please help me in the below you're showing my code in the web service and Mysql: php side and Web service:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
} else {
echo "invalid Data";
exit;
}
switch ($action) {
case "getRecord" :
getRecord($_REQUEST['ID'], $_REQUEST['email'], $_REQUEST['mobile']);
break;
.
.
.
.
default:
echo "Your action select is not true!";
}

FUNCTION getRecord($ID, $Email, $Mobile)
{
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "myDB");
/*mb_detect_encoding($ID,"ascii");
mb_detect_encoding($Mobile,"ascii");
mb_detect_encoding($Email,"ascii");*/
mb_convert_encoding($ID, 'ascii');
mb_convert_encoding($Email, 'ascii');
mb_convert_encoding($Mobile, 'ascii');

if (mb_check_encoding($ID, "UTF-8")) {
echo "UTF-8 Yes!!!" . PHP_EOL;
}
if (mb_check_encoding($Email, "UTF-8")) {
echo "UTF-8 Yes!!!" . PHP_EOL;
}
if (mb_check_encoding($Mobile, "UTF-8")) {
echo "UTF-8 Yes!!!" . PHP_EOL;
}


if (mb_check_encoding($ID, "ascii")) {
echo "ascii Yes!!!" . PHP_EOL;
}
if (mb_check_encoding($Email, "ascii")) {
echo "ascii Yes!!!" . PHP_EOL;
}
if (mb_check_encoding($Mobile, "ascii")) {
echo "ascii Yes!!!" . PHP_EOL;
}
if (is_int($ID)) {
echo "ID is Integer Yes!!!" . PHP_EOL;
} else {
echo "ID is not Integer!!!" . PHP_EOL;
}

if (is_int($Email)) {
echo "Email is Integer Yes!!!" . PHP_EOL;
} else {
echo "Email is not Integer!!!" . PHP_EOL;
}

if (is_int($Mobile)) {
echo "Mobile is Integer Yes!!!" . PHP_EOL;
} else {
echo "Mobile is not Integer!!!" . PHP_EOL;
}
//////////////////////////////
if (is_string($ID)) {
echo "ID is String Yes!!!" . PHP_EOL;
} else {
echo "ID is not String!!!" . PHP_EOL;
}

if (is_string($Email)) {
echo "Email is String Yes!!!" . PHP_EOL;
} else {
echo "Email is not String!!!" . PHP_EOL;
}

if (is_string($Mobile)) {
echo "Mobile is String Yes!!!" . PHP_EOL;
} else {
echo "Mobile is not String!!!" . PHP_EOL;
}


//$sql = "SET @p0=''$ID''; SET @p1=''$Email''; SET @p2=''$Mobile''; CALL `getRecord`(@p0, @p1, @p2);";
//$sql = "CALL getRecord(''$ID'',''$Email'',''$Mobile'');";
//$sql = "CALL getRecord(" + "'$ID'" + "," + "'$Email'" + "," + "'$Mobile'" + ");";
//$sql = "CALL getRecord(" + "'$ID'" + "," + "'$Email'" + "," + "'$Mobile'" + ");";
//$sql = "CALL getRecord('2261','saleh@gmail.com','+989999999999');";//this state is good word too, and show me true query 
$sql = "CALL getRecord('$ID','$Email','$Mobile');";
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect MySQL server" . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_set_charset($con, "ascii");
$resualt = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$records = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resualt)) {
$record = array();
$record['ID'] = $row['ID'];
$record['Name'] = $row['Name'];
$record['Family'] = $row['Family'];
$record['BirthDate'] = $row['BirthDate'];
$record['Email'] = $row['Email'];
$record['Mobile'] = $row['Mobile'];
$records[] = $record;
}
echo json_encode($records);
mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Sql side and procedure code :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `getRecord` (IN ID VARCHAR(166) CHARACTER SET ascii, IN EMail VARCHAR(166) CHARACTER SET ascii , IN Mobile VARCHAR(166) CHARACTER SET ascii) 
BEGIN
DECLARE CheckMe VARCHAR(166);
DECLARE CountRecords INT;
SET CheckMe = ( SELECT Count(*) FROM persons WHERE persons.Email = Email AND persons.Mobile = Mobile);
IF CheckMe = 1 THEN
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE persons.ID = ID;
ELSE 
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE persons.ID = 'xxxx';
END IF ;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I want response true query bro!!!

Comment: when I send parameter as type number or int with me response true query but when I send email and mobile parameter as type string not show me true query and always run else condition in the procedure

Comment: this problem when I work with http request and php web service and no problem within mySql environment

Comment: I have to say this is some very strange looking PHP code and it's done in a style I can't recognize. Why is there a stored procedure for running a simple query? What's with the rampant use of `PHP_EOL`? Is checking for UTF-8 strictly necessary? With the right server settings that shouldn't be a problem. I'm not sure what you're basing this code on, but it's full of some very unusual things that you should probably evaluate as to their actual utility.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: just I can say you thanks bro!!! really really useful MAN!!!